# AWT FileDialog - mac save as

Tags: java, macos, filedialog

Its possible to hide form "save as", when i use AWT FileDialog for choose directory (only directory mode), to save X files on mac?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. I would recommend you to use a JFileChooser instead.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, the issue with the swing classes on MacOS is that the JFileChooser doesn't have the same look and feel than the native dialog box that is used by the AWT classes.